# In R, how to refer to column name using variable in Base R and in data.table()?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

Is it possible to call a column name in R by referring to a variable, both in Base R and in `data.table()` when merging dataframes? I need both for my function.

1. I want to set a variable name `x` then filter my dataframe based on it, but I have to set the column name each time:

```
#my dataframe has a column named colname:
df$colname <- "some value"

#I want to specify a variable x, which is a string equal to colname
x <- "colname"

#Then I want to filter my data frame based on a reference file with a column "x"
df %>% filter(!df$products %in% reference$x) #this is wrong
```

Is there a way to directly call the column using my variable `x`?

2. I then need to refer to the same variable in data.table, so I can merge my data frames by `product` while I update the column `x`

```
setDT(df) 
setDT(reference) 
df[reference, on="products", x:=i.x] #this doesn't work
```

Could someone please help?

Comment: Read `help("$")`. It explains that you should use `reference[[x]]`.

Comment: Try: `filter(!df$products %in%  !! sym(x))`

Comment: Base R is easier here: `df[! df$products %in% df[[x]], ]`.

Comment: Perfect thanks a lot! Additionally how about in ```data.table()``` would it be possible for x as below, ```x:=i.x]```?    
    ```setDT(df) setDT(reference) df[reference, on="products", x:=i.x]```

Comment: See https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/articles/datatable-programming.html. The new programming syntax isn't on CRAN yet but the approach shown in "Computing on the language" always works in R.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly, you need to use `select` rather than `filter`(which works on rows, not columns):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  select(-x)
          colname2 colname3
1 some other value        1
2 some other value        2
3 some other value        3
4 some other value        4
5 some other value        5
```

Data:

```
x <- "colname"

df <- data.frame(
  colname = "some value",
  colname2 = "some other value",
  colname3 = 1:5
)
```

Comment: Actually, no, I just wanted to ask in addition if a similar thing can be done in `data.table()` to refer to the value that is updated.

Comment: Then why don't you say so in the post and/or tag it with `data.table`?

Comment: Sorry that was literally a post "post" additional question, that I need for the rest of my function. I have edited the question to include it.